# Insert blob image into QPixMap from sqlite db to QTextBrowser in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I can't insert qpixmap image to qtextbrowser with html tags. (I need to insert with html not other methods)

I tried the code below.

```py
def readImage(self):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        covers = cur.execute("select cover from covers")
        pm = QPixmap()
        for cover in covers:
            pm.loadFromData(cover[0])
            self.ui.textBrowser.setHtml("<img src=pm /img>")
```

The result is just a small icon which appears in qtextbrowser, but it doesn't show the actual image.
please don't give me a qt c++ doc page i can't understand those c++ stuff.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TRET9noXuvVJaqLd6SxSE6PGYPQlG_bP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to convert the data to QPixmap, if QtSql will return a QByteArray that can encode it to base64 making it possible to add the image to the QTextEdit:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql


def create_connection(path=":memory:"):
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(path)
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr(
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                "how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit."
            ),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        return False
    return True


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery("SELECT cover FROM covers")
        while query.next():
            ba = query.value(0)
            base64 = ba.toBase64().data().decode()
            self.text_edit.insertHtml(
                """<img height="200" width="200" src="data:image/png;base64,{}"/>""".format(base64)
            )
        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(current_dir, "rap.sqlite")

    if not create_connection(path):
        sys.exit(-1)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to continue using sqlite3 then you must convert the bytes to QByteArray and apply the same logic:

```py
import os
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        path = os.path.join(current_dir, "rap.sqlite")

        conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
        c = conn.cursor()

        covers = c.execute("SELECT cover FROM covers")
        for cover in covers:
            data, *_ = cover
            ba = QtCore.QByteArray(data)
            base64 = ba.toBase64().data().decode()
            self.text_edit.insertHtml(
                """<img height="200" width="200" src="data:image/png;base64,{}"/>""".format(base64)
            )
        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. it is working. is there a way to fit the image to qtextbrowser size? i don't want to resize the window itself. tnx.

Comment: @user2445398 Do you want to change the size of the images? If so, what size do you want it?

Comment: yes i want to change the image size when it is shown in textbrowser. I guess a size like 200 * 200 would be good.